# How many items can array in solidity return

Tags: solidity, arrays, storage

```
uint16[] ALLITEMS;

function _get() public view returns(uint16[] memory){
    uint16[] memory _list = ALLITEMS;
    return _list;   
}
```

> should I use "memory" or "storage" to call this? eventually, I may want to return 200-500 items here if needed. will this function fail?

Comment: Please, can you clarify and add more details about your question?

Comment: It depends on the purpose. By using memory it will create a copy of the array in memory and then again on the return. By using storage `_list` will be a reference to the storage location and only there will a copy to memory when returning. In any case you could write the function and evaluate them for gas consumption.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no limit to how many array items you can get from a `view` function IF you're calling it from outside the blockchain meaning you're using web3.js or a client library to access the data from the blockchain.

IF you're accessing the array from another smart contract you'll end up running into gas limits because even though it's a `view` function, it takes some gas to access each item. So you'll be able to read about 200 items from the array when calling it form the smart contract.